# Delphi Indy 9 Server Ports

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy, indy-9

I always worked with indy 9 and Delphi 7. I have quite experience with it now and but would like to go a little bit further. I would like to listen to multiple ports and don't know how I should do this. There are also concerns if I will be able to add/remove ports while the server is active. So here are a few questions I would like to know the answer to:

1. How can I add a new port to the bindings, while the server is already active?
2. How can I remove a port from the bindings, while the server is already active?
3. When I remove the bindings, how/will does Indy disconnect the clients from the port?
4. What happens to the defaultPort property?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Indy 10 is available since the days of Delphi 7 (more or less), and Indy 11 is under active development now and Indy 9 have no love for years, so, consider updating your code to Indy 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.How can I add a new port to the bindings, while the server is already active?
>
> 2.How can I remove a port from the bindings, while the server is already active?
>
> 3.When I remove the bindings, how/will does Indy disconnect the clients from the port?

All three questions have the same answer - what you are asking for is not supported (not even in Indy 10).  You must deactivate a server before you can make any changes to its `Bindings` collection.  If that does not suit your needs, then you will have to use a separate server component for each IP/Port pair you want to listen on.  That way, you can activate/deactivate them individually as needed.  Deactivating a server automatically disconnects all active clients that are connected to it.

> 4.What happens to the defaultPort property?

The `DefaultPort` property is only used to initialize the `TIdSocketHandle.Port` property when adding a new entry to the `Bindings` collection.  It is not used for anything else.

Comment: However I figured I can start new instances of TIdTCPServer. This would do the trick.